# Polars search sorted becomes scalar when used on column on length 1

Tags: python-polars

I have the following data:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("ix", [0], dtype=pl.UInt32),
        pl.Series("s1", [[4, 8]], dtype=pl.List(pl.Int64)),
        pl.Series("s2", [[5]], dtype=pl.List(pl.Int64)),
    ]
)
shape: (1, 3)
┌─────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ ix  ┆ s1        ┆ s2        │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ u32 ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ [4, 8]    ┆ [5]       │
└─────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

I want to run search_sorted on the columns in a groupby context:

```
res = df.groupby("ix").agg(
    [
        pl.col("s1").explode().search_sorted(pl.col("s2").explode(), side="left").alias("r1"),
        pl.col("s2").explode().search_sorted(pl.col("s1").explode(), side="left").alias("r2"),
    ]
)
shape: (1, 5)
┌─────┬───────────┬───────────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ ix  ┆ s1        ┆ s2        ┆ r1  ┆ r2        │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ u32 ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ u32 ┆ list[u32] │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ [4, 8]    ┆ [5]       ┆ 1   ┆ [0, 1]    │
└─────┴───────────┴───────────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

Note that r1 becomes a scalar. This happens when search_sorted is run on a list of length 1.

How do I avoid this? Even suggestions that only check whether the result is scalar and then turn it into a list will be upvoted, but I'd preferably accept an answer that explains why this happens and how to fix it.

It almost seems like a bug.

Comment: That does look like a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I created an issue here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9729